# What are the circled features on the upper surface of the A380 wing?

Tags: wing, feature-identification, airbus-a380

On the A380 wing are at least 3 red circle each side. There seems to be a black part inside. Is this a dip stick, or something else?

[image]

Comment: I think they are the indicators for the gear down/locked visual inspection.

Comment: Hi Ron, picture was taken on ground, gear down and locked. The gear system consists of body and wing landing gear each side. The number of 3 indicators would not fit.

Comment: The only thing I found from FCOM and 'Airplane Characteristics for Airport Planning', is that in each wing there is 'YELLOW HYDRAULIC GROUND CONNECTOR' and 'GREEN HYDRAULIC GROUND CONNECTOR'; however I am not sure if these are under the wing instead of on top.

Comment: @Afe: those are under, see FCOM 20-30 pages 10 and 11.

Answer (score 3):

They are likely attach points for safety harness equipment. Workers working on top of the wing attach gear that functions as anchors for lines that run the length of the wing, then attach their safety harness to the line.

[image]

Comment: The hole is as small as the rivets nearby. I highly doubt it's likely. The safety equipment shown could be based on suction (vacuum anchor).

Comment: Same method is used for all Airbus wings, but I don't remember similar things on the A320 wing (which I have observed a lot of times)

Comment: @ymb1 you don't need a huge orifice to support a simple line anchor. Suction is not an option, that is unsafe.

Comment: Also, if you look carefully, you'll also see that the anchors are also for the pneumatic hoses. The worker has a harness, and that has three lines, one for the tool, one to secure him to an anchor point behind him, and one to an anchor point in front of him.